# Laravel 5.2 eloquent model order by their relation model attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a question. I have an user model and a post model. A user can have many posts. Now I need to get posts with pagination. And I need to sort posts by their related user's id desc. Per page number is 10. I do not know how to write this code, someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Post` belongs to `User` the `posts` table has `user_id` key. Use it:

```
Post::orderBy('user_id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But what if now I need to paginate users, and sort them by their last post create time?